# Problemas ao acesar rota em laravel para deletar usando Vue.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js-2

Estou querendo deletar um registro, mas quando acesso a rota do laravel usando o **this.$http.delete** me retorna o erro **419 unknown status**

Metodo laravel

```
public function destroy(Request $request){
    return User::destroy($request['id']);
}
```

Rota:

```
Route::delete('user/delete/{id}', 'Admin\UserAccessController@destroy');
```

Vue:

```
deleteUser: function(id){

        this.$http.delete(this.$root.baseUrl + 'user/delete/'+id).then((response) => {
            if (response == 1) {
                this.users = this.deleteFromArray(this.users,id);
                this.$root.$refs.toastr.s('Usuário deletado com sucesso!');
            } else {
                this.$root.$refs.toastr.e('Não foi possível deletar o usuário!');
            }
        }).catch(function(e) {
            console.log(e);
            this.$root.$refs.toastr.e('Ocorreu um erro ao deletar usuário!');
        });

    },
```

Alguem sabe o que pode ser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É nescessário colocar um header.Ficou assim:

```
this.$http.delete(this.$root.baseUrl + 'user/delete/'+id,{headers:{
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }})
```